# passing variable in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm not sure how it is called and with limited search i didn't find what i was looking for, so I'll explain:

I've got route login in which i get 2 parameters, key and callbackURL:

```
app.get('/login*', function (req, res) {
  var adr = url.parse(req.url, true)

  var key = adr.query.key
  var callbackURL = adr.query.callbackURL

  if (key == "key123") {
    res.render('index', { resp: '', callbackURL: callbackURL })
  } else {
    res.render('error')
  }
})
```

so if the key matches it renders index.ejs with empty response and callbackURL. Is there a way I can pass that callbackURL later in '/submit' when user tries to log in?
submit code:

```
app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
  request.post({
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    url: <here to use callbackURL>,// <-- here
    body: { 'login': req.body.login, 'password': req.body.password },
    json: true
  },
    function (request, response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.render('index', { resp: 'login succesfull' })
      } else {
        res.render('index', { resp: 'invalid login or password' })
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in a different function, so the variable isn't available.

You would need to pass it somehow.

You could pass it to the client when you render the page (in fact you already are passing it to the render method), then put it inside a hidden input in your form, and then read it from the form data when you submit endpoint is called.

You could, alternatively, store it in a session, but that would be at risk of race conditions.

Comment: I didn't thought of that, great, thanks! much simpler than I assumed. :D

Comment: I thought it was easy but I have no clue how to pass it in hidden input and read it in submit... are you able to post a solution to it? @Quentin